Uni-directional OneToOne mapping in entity with primary key side
I have two tables.
Student: id, name
Email: id, email_address, student_id

Here "student_id" is a foreign key which refers to the id in the person table.
Consider, that each student will have only one email and each email is associated with only one person.
I want to access Email data in a person entity but not vice versa.
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMAIL")
public class Email {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS")
    private int emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID", unique = true)
    private String studentId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;

    // uni-directional One to one mapping
    private Email email;
}


As each Email is associated with only one Student, we will use a unidirectional @OneToOne mapping in the Student entity.
Here are steps to implement the logic
1 ) Updated Email Entity
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMAIL")
public class Email {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    // Remove the "STUDENT_ID" column, as the relationship will be managed from the `Student` entity

    // Getters and setters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}

2 ) Updated Student Entity
@JoinColumn refers to the actual column that is present in the student table.
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;

    // Unidirectional One-to-One mapping with Email
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true)
    private Email email;

    // Getters and setters
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Email getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Email email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}

3 ) Define StudentRepository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
}

4 ) Define Student Service
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public void displayStudentEmail(int studentId) {
        studentRepository.findById(studentId).ifPresent(student -> {
            System.out.println("Student Name: " + student.getName());
            System.out.println("Student Email: " + student.getEmail().getEmailAddress());
        });
    }
}

Revision : I revised my answer through @JoinColumn(name = "EMAIL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true)

I have tried this code and got JDBC exception. This is the query, spring is executing when i tried to find student by id
" select
s1_0.id,
s1_0.age,
e1_0.id,
e1_0.email_address,
s1_0.name
from
student s1_0
left join
email e1_0
on e1_0.id=s1_0.student_id
where
s1_0.id=? "

It is trying to access student_id from student table, but it should be in Email.
Just a quick question, what will be the difference in @JoinColumn if i want to access Student in Email (I think it is also same).

@r_smk Can you share the log?

Here is the log: https://dontpad.com/log
